# I want to save that mobile number after share picture on whatsapp

Tags: android

I am very new in android. In my app I want to share some picture from my app to `WhatsApp` and get that shared `WhatsApp` number to store somewhere. I am able to share picture but unable to get and store that number. If it is possible then how I can do that. Please help me.

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

Comment: Sorry my friend but this is not possible.

Comment: You can not do this .. `Intent.ACTION_SEND` does not provide a Result back ..

Comment: How can I do this...tell me...